# python str Text equal name of dict

Tags: python

Can you tell me why its not working?

Code:

```
DictModels = {'DDR3 4GB 1333Mhz' : 4}
Text = 'DDR3 4GB 1333Mhz'
for j in range(len(DictModels)):
      Klopo = str(list(DictModels)[j])
      if  Klopo is Text:
        Text = 'it work'
```

Comment: If you `print(Text)` -> *"it work"*

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked up how the "is" operator works? What benefit is there to converting your dictionary to a list?

Comment: What about: `text in DictModels.values()` instead of iteration through your dictionary

Comment: @JvdV: probably `text in DictModels`.

Comment: @Austin, thanks, indeed it's the keys that need to be compared =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `in` operator be a good alternative for you, instead of iteration?

```
DictModels = {'DDR3 4GB 1333Mhz' : 4}
Text = 'DDR3 4GB 1333Mhz'
if Text in DictModels:
    print('it worked')
```

This operator would check if your variable is fount in the keys of the dictionary instead of an iteration over the whole dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

you are doing an object comparison

```
if Klopo is Text:
```

You should be comparing the value

```
if Klopo == Text:
```

additionally you probably want to print "it works"

```
print("it Works")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, maybe provide the appropriate code (earlier was an example)

```
DictModels = {}
    NrChild = request.POST.get('NrPop')
    for i in range(int(NrChild)):
        if i==0:
            Text = (request.POST.get('GB')) + "GB"
            title = request.POST.get('ChoiceFieldComputer')
            Text += " " + SpecRamAdd.objects.get(id=int(title)).Ram + " "
            DictModels[Text] = int(request.POST.get('NrStack'))
        else:
            j = 0
            numberTake = str(i+1)
            Text = str(request.POST.get('GB' + numberTake)) + "GB"
            title = request.POST.get('ChoiceFieldComputer' + numberTake)
            Text += " " + SpecRamAdd.objects.get(id=int(title)).Ram
            for j in range(len(DictModels)):
                if  str(list(DictModels)[j]) == Text:
                    DictModels.values()[j] += int(request.POST.get('NrStack' + str(numberTake)))
                else:
                    DictModels[Text] = int(request.POST.get('NrStack' + str(numberTake)))
    Text = str(DictModels)
    TextMail = {
        'ShowText': Text,
    }
    return render(request, 'Order.html', TextMail)
```

I choose computer models and how much RAM I need. Then I wanted to display the paragraph ('< p >') with the names of the Rams and the number of pieces. Sometimes two different models have the same name Rams, so I just want to add the number of pieces. So I dont wan this:

```
DDR3 1666 Mhz x3
DDR3 1333 Mhz x2
DDR3 1333 Mhz x1
```

I want like that:

```
DDR3 1666 Mhz x3
DDR3 1333 Mhz x3
```

In paragraph this: str(list(DictModels)[j]) is this same text as variable Text. So why '==' its not working? I coded earlier in c #.

Comment: Guys, sory for a waste of time :) Now I see that is not this same text :P